# Number of different factorizations

Tags: factorization, arithmetic-functions

I define $\nu(n)$ the number of different factorizations for an integer $n$. I know there are papers about $\delta(n)$ the number of dividers for an integer $n$ (Landau, Euler, Dirichlet) but I still found nothing about $\nu(n)$.

Has someone any idea of a limit for $\nu(n)$ as $n\to\infty$ ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "factorizations"? Do $6=2\cdot 3=3\cdot 2$ count as different factorizations? Do $6=2\cdot 3=1\cdot 2\cdot 3$?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for https://oeis.org/A001055 "The multiplicative partition function: number of ways of factoring $n$ with all factors greater than $1$."